# Magento2.4: How to check if a customer is offline/online in custom module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to check if a customer is logged-In or logged-out on fronted store, and save that customer status in a custom table and that status update whenever a customer logged-In and logged-out in that table.

[image]

Comment: something like that if a customer is logged in on frontend then the value should be like offline or logged in and if he is logged out of not using frontend store then value should be loggged out , the customer loggin status should be updated whenever we open grid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Add custom field to customer listing**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="online_status" class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerOnline" sortOrder="300">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Online Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**2. Create custom Online Column**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomerOnline.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor\CollectionFactory as VisitorCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class CustomerOnline extends Column
{
    protected Visitor                  $visitorModel;
    protected VisitorCollectionFactory $visitorCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Visitor $visitorModel,
        VisitorCollectionFactory $visitorCollectionFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->visitorModel             = $visitorModel;
        $this->visitorCollectionFactory = $visitorCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    protected function getOnlineCustomers(array $customerIds): array
    {
        $collection = $this->visitorCollectionFactory->create();
        $lastDate = gmdate('U') - $this->visitorModel->getOnlineInterval() * 60;
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('last_visit_at', [
            'from' => $collection->getConnection()->formatDate($lastDate),
        ]);
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', [
            'in' => $customerIds,
        ]);

        $online = [];
        foreach ($collection as $visitor) {
            $online[$visitor->getCustomerId()] = true;
        }

        return $online;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $entityIds = [];
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $item) {
                $entityIds[] = $item['entity_id'];
            }
            $online = $this->getOnlineCustomers($entityIds);
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$this->getName()] = isset($online[$item['entity_id']]) ? __('Online') : __('Offline');
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day.